# How to handle unseen words for pre-trained Glove word-embedding to avoid keyerror?

Tags: python, nlp, word-embedding

I want to extract features from pre-trained Glove embedding. But I got Keyerror  for certain words. Here is the list of word token.

```
words1=['nuclear','described', 'according', 'called','physics', 'account','interesting','holes','theoretical','like','space','radiation','property','impulsed','darkfield']
```

I got Keyerror from 'impulsed', 'darkfield' words because probably these are the unseen words. How can I avoid this error ? .

Here is my full code:

```
gloveFile = "glove.6B.50d.txt"
import numpy as np
def loadGloveModel(gloveFile):
    print ("Loading Glove Model")
    with open(gloveFile, encoding="utf8" ) as f:
        content = f.readlines()
    model = {}
    for line in content:
        splitLine = line.split()
        word = splitLine[0]
        embedding = np.array([float(val) for val in splitLine[1:]])
        model[word] = embedding
    print ("Done.",len(model)," words loaded!")
    return model

model = loadGloveModel(gloveFile)

words1=['nuclear','described', 'according', 'called','physics', 'account','interesting','holes','theoretical','like','space','radiation','property','impulsed','darkfield']

import numpy as np
vector_2 = np.mean([model[word] for word in words1],axis=0) ## Got error message
```

Error message for 'impulsed' word

[image]

### Is there any way to skip these unseen words?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest below

- All missing words assigned to some unique vector (say all zeros)
- Find words similar to it and use their embedding:

  - Try ngrams (prefix or suffux) of the words and check if it is in vocab
  - Stem the word and check if it is in vocab
- Simplest Solution: Use FastText. It assembles word vectors from subword n-grams which allows it to handle out of vocabulary words.